# Sizing a hybrid bike

Tags: hybrid-bike, cannondale, size

I'm 180cm tall, with a bicycle inseam of 81cm (without shoes) and a wingspan of 190cm.

I'm looking at the Cannondale Bad Boy 1 2019 hybrid bike which you can see the geometry for [here](https://static.evanscycles.com/production/pdf-media/sizing-table/Cannondale_Bad_Boy_2019_Geometry_Chart.pdf). Based on my understanding, the medium size is probably the best fit, but seems to be discontinued.

Would the large or the small be a decent fit for me? Or should I just look for a different bike?

Comment: To size  a bike you really need to test ride it. Things like flexibility can make a big difference to  the size frame that is ideal for you.  That said, a large frame will be more suitable than a small, and I suspect at 180 you would be better on a large frame anyway.

Comment: Yeah that would be ideal, however there are no stores in my area that stock the bike. I’m currently looking around for store with similar bikes. My main concern with the large (based on the geometry) is the stand over height. It says 83.3cm, which is larger than my inseam. Thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: If your inseam is smaller than the standover height, then the bike doesn't fit. Your long arms and long torso will likely mean that the next size down won't fit you either, because the reach won't be long enough. Unfortunately not all bikes have a size that fits everyone. I would recommend looking for a hybrid with a long toptube relative to the standover height which will be more likely to fit you. Again, you will want to test ride before buying, because there's more to fitting than just bike/body measurements.

Comment: You may find that you need to make some changes to whatever you buy. A longer stem seems quite likely